# Razor page routing and FileSystem routing

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a razor page `MyPage.cshtml` with the following annotation

```
@page "{id}"
```

It is there so I can have a route that looks like this;

```
/MyPage/Blah
```

This all works.
When I see stuff like the following;

```
/MyPage/Blah/content/somefile.js
```

it results in a `404`.
I would like that to be handled by the filesystem.
I do have the following file in;

```
wwwroot/MyPage/Blah/content/somefile.js
```

I am using asp.net core 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,I test the code,and I can work.

And then I find if I delete `app.UseStaticFiles();` in my startup.cs.I can get the same error with you.
So you can check if you can access other file in wwwwroot.If not,you can check your startup.cs,and add `app.UseStaticFiles();` like this in Configure:

```
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
```

Comment: The out of the box routing works.  I had a messed up UseBlazorFrameworkFiles that was interfering with the static file routes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have other routes that mess with static file routes.
i.e. UseBlazorFrameworkFiles was my issue.

Ok, so out of the box asp.net core 3.1 will route to my page;

```
/MyPage
```

and if I have a bunch of static files in

```
wwwroot/MyPage/some.js
```

it will pull that too.
All good.

I was getting other route problems when my page was hosting a blazor app and had non-file client side routes.

To make sure routes where being properly handled in all those cases I had to add the following to my razor page.

```
@page "{id}/{*path:nonfile}"
```

So when I got a whole page refresh for

```
/MyPage/MyBlazorApp/counter
```

My page now handles the `/MyPage/MyBlazorApp` portion and the rest gets handed off to the client-side blazor app to finally go to the client-side route: `/MyPage/MyBlazorApp/counter`